# Passing Data Through Pages with Vue

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js

I receive data in a function and this function needs to load a new page. I was doing this with Jquery using the method .load(), But my vue method gets an error saying that can not find the element in the other page.I believe that could be a better approach, but I do not know how I can pass data through a vue component

```
static foo(a,b){
    $('#maindiv').load("/newPage");
    new Vue({
        el: '#newPageElem',
        data: {
            vueVar1:a
            vueVar2:b
        },

    });
}
```

How can I do that? I believe that using Jquery is not the best way to achieve this, but I dont know how to change routes with vue and passing parameter between them.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look at [Vue-router](http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html) which allows you to map components to routes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at `vue-router` here: http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html - it allows you to handle all the client-side routes.

For making http calls to receive data from server, you can use `vue-resource` (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource)

It is better to avoid mixing jQuery with Vue, as Vue is responsible for rendering the DOM. If you make any DOM changes with jQuery, it will get over-written by Vue in the next DOM update. So you will end up spending a lot of time in debugging.

Also, you cannot instantiate a Vue app inside a function, as seen in your code example, unless you call the function on page load. Ideally, the first few lines of script should start the Vue app.

Comment: So how would I call the method when the page is loaded? Should I make a script tag in the html page?

Comment: Yes, you can use a script tag at the bottom of html page for `new Vue({..})` which will initiate the Vue app and render the DOM. Or you may check out `vue-cli` which may be a bit confusing if you are just getting started.

Comment: @Mani It's great that you point out the problems of the code example besides answer the question, it's helpful for us who new to vue. Thank you very much!